# Azure SQL Database Firewall and Login Error

Tags: sql-server, azure

Lately I got Microsoft Imagine (dreamspark) subscription as a student. and wanted to change from my mysql db, to SQL Azure DB. connection strings are fixed. everything works fine with Microsoft SQL Server Management(for local DB).

But when I try to connect to azure db, from Microsoft SQL Server Management
I keep getting this error:

[image: Image 1]

I searched about it, and the recomandation most people gave is to check the fire-wall IP to allow the computer to connect.

But since my project is going to be addressed to a lot of people (more than 200) and maybe more. I can not write that much IP, and fix them every time they change.

So I made something like this:
[image: Image 2]

But I still keep getting the same error.
I thought it might work, but looks like not. Does any one have a better solution? or way to help me?

Comment: Looks like that you want to allow direct access to your SQL database to the whole world - that's not a good idea. Usually you create some services / web apps / whatever hosted in azure, which acts as a client for database, and a server for your needs.

Comment: Im creating a hospital management system for the entire country.
so, people from many cities might join. How can I do it in a better way?

Comment: If you allow direct access to DB, you will also provide some client which use this access. You will require these clients or end-users to know login/pass to db. As a result it becomes very easy to obtain such login/pass, and having direct access to DB from any place in the world it becomes easy to copy / change / delete data. Having in mind that might be private medical data, you are in weak position here. Usual way is to NOT provide direct access to DB. You will need to implement some backend client, like web service or web app for this.

Comment: @Lanorkin Thanks, but why am I not able to connect thru SQL server management to my database?

Comment: You should add your *external* IP to firewall exceptions in azure. You can check your external IP with services like https://myexternalip.com/ (or even typing "external IP" in google)

Comment: @Lanorkin I've added that, that is not the problem, error 40, shows that the server could not be found.

Comment: Network name you use on screenshot cannot be resolved (I used `nslookup projecthelix.database.windows.net`) - ensure you typed it correctly; you can follow these advises to obtain server name https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-connectivity-issues/#connections-to-azure-sql-database If that not helped you can use MS troubleshooter https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10085/troubleshooting-connectivity-issues-with-microsoft-azure-sql-database

Answer (score -1):

Reset the start IP to 0.0.0.0 when you wanted every one to access it. Or if you are accessing ti from localhost set ( 127.0.0.1). Try this if it works other you need to check int the firewall of your system.